# In handlebars main.hbs page is not loading

Tags: html, node.js, express, express-handlebars

In handlebar main.hbs page s not loading
below is
app.js

// Handlebars
app.engine(
'.hbs',
engine({
defaultLayout: 'main',
extname: '.hbs',
})
)
app.set('view engine', '.hbs')
app.set('views', './views');

```
main.hbs
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-             2/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha256-46r060N2LrChLLb5zowXQ72/iKKNiw/lAmygmHExk/o=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
<title>KadhaStore</title>
</head>

<body>
{{> _header}} <!---partial file u can include like this --->

<div class="container">
    {{{body}}}
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.14.1/ckeditor.js"
    integrity="sha256-bEIQpI72w9NJuIVhTLFUF2/8uxl0u5800r8ddViuv+o=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


 </body>

</html>
```

```
_header.hbs
```

```
<nav class="grey darken-3">
<div class="nav-wrapper container">

    <a href="#!" class="brand-logo center">Kadhas</a>
    <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger show-on-large"><i class="fas fa-bars">         

   </i></a>
    <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
        <li><a href="/kadha">Kadha</a></li>
        <li><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="/auth/logout">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

I tried app.engine() to change main.hbs but did not work for me

Comment: sorry I am new here so donot know how to ask question

Comment: Please format the code to make it more readable.